# Get the body of a stored procedure from PostgreSQL using JDBC

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I can't get a stored procedure's body from Java code using JDBC.

Which methods should I use to solve this?

I found the metadata of all stored procedures using this code:

```
ResultSet resultSet1 = databaseMetaData.getProcedures(connection.getCatalog(), "public", resultSet.getString(3));
```

But I want to get the whole body of the stored procedures body in a `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the String value of a SP body, you should execute this SQL:

```
SELECT pg_get_functiondef((
          SELECT oid
          FROM pg_proc
          WHERE pronamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
            AND proname = 'your_proc_name'
       ));
```

And write the result to String.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind querying the database directly, try

```
SELECT proname, prosrc
FROM pg_proc
WHERE pronamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
```

Comment: So, without SQL I can't get the body ?

Comment: I don't know; I didn't check the JDBC documentation.